# Can we run a Perl script in a browser without web server?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to run a perl script in Activeperl without web server in windows 7.If possible what are the steps to follow?

I have simple registration form using Post method in HTML file.I'm using this HTML file in my .pl file.I'm using CGI module. While running the .pl file from the command promt the HTML file is running browser, after clicking submit button   the perl script is displaying.

Comment: Double click it in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

When you install ActivePerl, it creates a file association for .pl files, so simply double-clicking a .pl file in Explorer ("My Computer", "File Explorer", etc) will run it. This also makes it so you can run `script.pl` from the Windows Command Prompt.

When you install ActivePerl, it modifies your PATH to include the directory that contains `perl.exe`, making it so you can run `perl script.pl` from the Windows Command Prompt.

Finally, you can always run `c:\...\bin\perl script.pl` from the Windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a bit more the exact use-case?

I think the first user in the comments gave you the best answer.

If Perl is not in your PATH environment you need to associate .pl extensions with Perl or run it via command-line ( if I remember correctly Active-Perl comes with a Perl command line tool )

Comment: Re "*if I remember correctly Active-Perl comes with a Perl command line tool*", Well, it is a Perl interpreter, which is a command-line tool.

Comment: indeed but Perl is not in the path by default. they supply a designated command-line as a perl product ( adlist strawberry perl does ) in which Perl is already in the PATH

Comment: 1) The installer DOES add Perl's directory to the PATH. 2) ActivePerl DOESN'T "supply a designated command-line as a perl product"; ActivePerl is such a product.

Comment: that's why I wrote "if I remember correctly" . Strawberry Perl adds it for sure

Comment: I know. That's why I told you it is added to the PATH. Now go fix the problems.